# How does Browser back button handle Automatic URL redirection?

Tags: java, url, browser, javafx, redirect

I am trying to create a browser to get the hands on practice on JavaFX. I implemented the Back button with Stack.

1. When the URL of the page change, add url to Stack(java.util.Stack)
2. When back button is pressed, pop 1 item from Stack and show the page

But this does not work in case of URL redirection. Eg. I entered http://www.google.com , It automatically redirects to http://www.google.co.in (India). This makes 2 entries in Stack which corrupts the Back button logic since the page is the same but taken from different locations.

Please assist me in fixing this problem.

Thanks for your help

```
webEngine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            //urlField is a text Field
            urlField.setText(newValue);
            addURLToStack(oldValue);
            if(backButtonStack.size() ==1){ //means on last url of Stack
                backButton.setDisable(true);
            }
            else{
                backButton.setDisable(false); 
            }}      
    });
 backButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(backButtonStack != null && !backButtonStack.isEmpty()){
                String poppedURL = backButtonStack.pop();
                webEngine.load(poppedURL);

            }
        }

    });
private void addURLToStack(String url) {
    if(backButtonStack == null){
        backButtonStack = new Stack<String>();
    }

    backButtonStack.push(url);
}
```

Comment: Don't use java.util.Stack, it's deprecated! Use LinkedList and it's interface Deque. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but even if I use linked list, my original problem remains as is. Extra value would be added to Linked List instead of Stack in Automatic URL redirects

Comment: Can you add some of your code please? I think it will be easy to understand your problem

Comment: webEngine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    //urlField is a text Field
                urlField.setText(newValue);
                addURLToStack(oldValue);
                if(backButtonStack.size() ==1){ //means on last url of Stack
                    backButton.setDisable(true);
                }
                else{
                    backButton.setDisable(false); 
    }}      
        });

Comment: No-no-no!=) Add this code to your question, and put it in tag "code" please!)

Comment: Please, add code of addURLToStack method and code of back button listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to solve this problem.

JavaFX [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebHistory.html) has a [WebHistory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebHistory.html) object which has all the API you need to completely manage the history and it should take care of not adding redirected URLs to the history for you.  And, if you don't want to use that, you can use `webengine.executeScript("history.back()");` to have the engine's JavaScript engine handle the navigation for you.

What Chris Gerken says is right about monitoring the http status return codes to work out whether or not to place the object in history.  The difficulty with that in the JavaFX `WebEngine` is that the http status return codes happen at the network layer and are not exposed through the WebEngine interface.  So if you just monitor the location property of the WebEngine as you are doing, it is going to be really hard to get a high quality navigation interface.  I found this out when I implemented a JavaFX WebBrowser to get JavaFX experience and [my browser's history mechanism using an ObservableList with a current index pointer](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/src/main/java/org/jewelsea/willow/History.java) had exactly the same issue as you point out in your question.  If I were to implement the same functionality again today, I would just make use of the new `WebHistory` functionality provided by the later JavaFX versions, rather than writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you will need to handle redirects in your logic. Whenever re-directs happen; do not put the original URL in your data structure ( stack or LinkedQueue whatever ); only put final URL in your data structure. You might even face conditions when 2-3 redirects happen. You need to make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your stack only the URL's that you actually display.  On a send redirect, you'll get back a status code of 307 along with the new URL.  only put that URL in your stack (unless by some bizarre chance you get yet another 307 back... but you get the idea).

And you probably want to use a list instead of a stack.  That will let you go forward as well as back.  You probably need to hold on to other things, too, like the HTTP verb used, etc.